# Myfaces Trinidad JSF: Ajax problem when sending Non US-ASCII Characters

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, websphere, myfaces, trinidad

**The Issue:**

We have a Java web application, based on Apache MyFaces Trinidad. We are facing some problems when trying to partial submit (that's it: via Ajax) a form, when a field contains some special characters, such as Ñ, á, etc.

When we write a value like `camión` at the text field, the resulting message is `Hola cami` (it drops the special char, and the next one).

The application server we are runnign our code at is IBM WebSphere AS 7.0.

This behaviour has been observed on IExplorer and Firefox browsers, all run from Windows XP Professional (spanish version).

**Main code snippets**:

**UPDATE:** based on `lkdg`'s answer (thanks), I have updated the JSP and resulting HTML code snippets.

JSP Page Code:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" prefix="tr" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html" prefix="trh" %>  

<f:view>  
    <tr:document>  
        <trh:head title="Prueba de AJAX con todas las Cabeceras">  
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>  
        </trh:head>  

        <tr:form>
        <tr:panelHorizontalLayout halign="left">
            <f:facet name="separator">
                <tr:spacer width="10" height="5"/>
            </f:facet>

            <tr:inputText id="elCampo" label="Your name" value="#{commandButtonBean.name}"
                          requiredMessageDetail="Name is required"

                          />
            <tr:commandButton id="sayHello" text="Say Hello"
                              partialSubmit="true" 
                              action="#{commandButtonBean.sayHello}"
                              />
        </tr:panelHorizontalLayout>

        <tr:spacer height="15px"/>
        <tr:outputText value="#{commandButtonBean.message}" partialTriggers="sayHello" 
                       inlineStyle="font-weight: bold;"/>
        </tr:form>
    </tr:document>  
</f:view>
```

This is the resulting HTML output (removed some empty lines):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Document["j_id_jsp_1876237926_1"]--><html dir="ltr" lang="es-ES">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content="Apache MyFaces Trinidad">

    <link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" type="text/css" href="/ModuloTrinidadPilotoWeb/adf/styles/cache/bigfont-desktop-nur72r-ltr-gecko.css">
  </head>
  <!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Document["j_id_jsp_1876237926_1"]-->
  <body onload="_checkLoad()" onunload="_checkUnload(event)"><script type="text/javascript">var _AdfWindowOpenError='Se ha detectado un bloqueo de ventana emergente en el explorador. Estos bloqueos interfieren con el funcionamiento de esta aplicación. Desactívelo o permita elementos emergentes desde esta dirección.';</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/ModuloTrinidadPilotoWeb/adf/jsLibs/Common1_2_10.js"></script><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Document["j_id_jsp_1876237926_1"]--><div id="tr_pprBlockingDiv" onclick="return _pprConsumeClick(event);" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;width:0;height:0;cursor:wait;" onkeydown="return false;" onkeyup="return false;" onmousedown="return false;" onmouseup="return false;" onkeypress="return false;"></div><a name="top"></a>

    <noscript>Esta p&aacute;gina utiliza JavaScript y necesita un explorador activado para JavaScript. Su explorador no est&aacute; activado para JavaScript.</noscript>
    <!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Head["j_id_jsp_1876237926_2"]-->
    <head>
      <title>Prueba de AJAX con todas las Cabeceras</title>

      <meta name="generator" content="Apache MyFaces Trinidad">

      <link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" type="text/css" href="/ModuloTrinidadPilotoWeb/adf/styles/cache/bigfont-desktop-nur72r-ltr-gecko.css">

           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>  
        </head>

    <!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Form["j_id_jsp_1876237926_3"]-->
    <form id="j_id_jsp_1876237926_3" name="j_id_jsp_1876237926_3" style="margin:0px" method="POST" onkeypress="return _submitOnEnter(event,'j_id_jsp_1876237926_3');" action="/ModuloTrinidadPilotoWeb/jsp/sgtc/pruebaAjax2.faces"><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Panel["j_id_jsp_1876237926_4"]--><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary=""><tr>
          <td><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Input["elCampo"]--><table id="elCampo__xc_" class="af_inputText" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary=""><tr>
                <td class="af_inputText_label" nowrap><span id="elCampo::icon" style="display:none;"><a name="_msgAnc_elCampo" title="Error" class="AFErrorIconStyle">X</a></span>&nbsp;<label for="elCampo">Your name</label></td>

                <td valign="top" nowrap class="AFContentCell"><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Input["elCampo"]--><input id="elCampo" name="elCampo" class="af_inputText_content" size="30" type="text"></td>
              </tr><tr>
                <td></td>

                <td class="AFComponentMessageCell"><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Input["elCampo"]--><span id="elCampo::msg" class="OraInlineErrorText"></span></td>

              </tr></table></td>

          <td><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Object["j_id_jsp_1876237926_5"]--><img src="/ModuloTrinidadPilotoWeb/adf/images/t.gif" alt="" width="10" height="5"></td>

          <td><script type="text/javascript">var _pprUpDatemode=false;function _adfspu(f,v,e,s,o){_pprUpdateMode=true;if(!o)o=new Object();if(e)o.event=e;if(s)o.source=s;_submitPartialChange(f,v,o);}</script><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Command["sayHello"]-->
            <button id="sayHello" name="sayHello" type="button" onclick="TrPage._autoSubmit('j_id_jsp_1876237926_3','sayHello',event,1);return false;" class="af_commandButton">Say Hello</button>
          </td>
        </tr></table><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Object["j_id_jsp_1876237926_8"]--><div style="margin-top:15px"></div><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Output["j_id_jsp_1876237926_9"]--><span id="j_id_jsp_1876237926_9" style="font-weight: bold;"></span><input type="hidden" name="org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM" value="j_id_jsp_1876237926_3"><!--Start: org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.Form--><span id="tr_j_id_jsp_1876237926_3_Postscript"><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" value="!-4fd3ee50"><script type="text/javascript">function _j_id_jsp_1876237926_3Validator(f,s){return _validateInline(f,s);}var j_id_jsp_1876237926_3_SF={};</script></span><script type="text/javascript">_submitFormCheck();</script></form>
  </body>

  <!--Created by Apache Trinidad (Apache MyFaces Trinidad API - 1.2.10/Apache MyFaces Trinidad Impl - 1.2.10), skin:bigfont.desktop (bigfont)--></html>
```

The CommandButton bean code:

```
public class CommandButtonBean {
    public String name;
    public String message;

    public String sayHello(){
        message = "Hola " + name;
        return "";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

Of course, the command button is configured at faces-config.xml (I think that this snippet is not relevant).

**Attempted fixes so far:**

- We have checked the charset encoding at different levels (application, JVM, etc). It seems to be aligned between the differen layers.
- Also, we have included at web.xml the next context parameter:

  ```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>PARAMETER_ENCODING</param-name> 
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value> 
  </context-param>
  ```
- We have logged what is the value
  passed as an argument to the
  `setName` method, for if it could be
  an error at writing the response. The
  value passed is already wrong.
- We have tried to write a web Filter,
  to set the request charset to UTF-8 (just in
  case, you know). But when logging the
  parameter values at the filter, we
  got the wrong value too.
- At last we removed the
  `partialSubmit` attribute of the
  submit button, and got the right
  value. But this won't really fix our
  problem, as we are trying to
  implement some inline searches and
  validations (we don't want to repaint
  the whole page).

So, when we send a normal POST message, we get the expected result, but when we try to use the Ajax approach, we loose these special characters.

**And, at last, The Question:**

Have you any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post a small snippet of the generated HTML page, atleast the meta and header sections. It's always good to check what it is that's really output to the browser. Also, what app server and browser are you using.

Comment: what do you mean by *"... when sending non Unicode characters"*?  The 'U' in UTF-8 stands for Unicode and Ñ, á exists in Unicode.  Shouldn't you rephrase your question to *"...when sending Unicode characters"*?

Comment: @Gugusse: I was referring to the US-ASCII chars. I have fixed to avoid confussion. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with trinidad&WAS: http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@myfaces.apache.org/msg46298.html . You will have to make a small modification to two js files, you need to encode the sent characters (the solution there by Naveen Ravindra works). Edit these files:

- trinidad-impl-XXX.jar\META-INF\adf\jsLibsDebug\xhr\XMLRequest.js
- trinidad-impl-XXX.jar\META-INF\adf\jsLibs\xhr\XMLRequest.js

Add this new function to them (paste this to the beginning of the js:

```
function encodeCharacters(string) {
        string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";
    for ( var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
        var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
        if (c < 128) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
        } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }   
        else {  
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
            utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
        }
    }
    return utftext;
}
```

Change the `TrXMLRequest.prototype.send` function in the same js. In it change

- `xmlhttp.send(content);` to `xmlhttp.send(encodeCharacters(content));` in the debug version, and
- `a4.send(a3);` to `a4.send(encodeCharacters(a3));` in the production version.

Tested, works in WAS 7.0.0.11.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I can't reproduce your problem. Actually I don't get anything going if I try to program the jsp Page like you did. This is how my jsp's look like

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" prefix="tr" %>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html" prefix="trh" %>  
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  
<f:view>  
<tr:document>  
<trh:head title="Your Title">  
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>  
</trh:head>  
</tr:document>  
</f:view>
```

The tr:document, which you don't use creates a html, body and head tag.
You can use trh:head if you need it.
See trinidad's documentation:
[Documentation tr:document](http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_document.html)

With this configuration I had no problem with an ó.
I have no PARAMETER_ENCODING set in web.xml and I am using jsf1.2 trinidad 1.2.14
This is not really an answer but it probably helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for you answer (+1). Tried it, but still the behaviour i get with ó, á, etc, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've forgotten trinidad a bit, but in order for the button to affect the input text, dont you need a "partialTriggers" attribute set on the inputText component, which should have the ID of the button?

Comment: No, as far as I know. The code works (kind of), setting the Name value, and showing the message at the tr:outputText (there is where I have set a partialTriggers attribute). Only the message showed has an issue with the non ASCII chars

Comment: Aah yes you're right. What happens if you set the value of the input field in the back end.. does this properly show up in the inputfield after a (partial)reload?

Answer (score 0):

it is lkdg again

I tried to reproduce your issue.

jsp:

```
<tr:inputText
  id="myfield"
   value="#{myBean.myname}">
</tr:inputText>
<tr:commandButton 
   id="sayHello" 
   text="Say Hello" 
   partialSubmit="true"                                
   action="#{myBean.sayHello}"/>
<tr:outputText 
   value="#{myBean.message}" 
   partialTriggers="sayHello"
   inlineStyle="font-weight: bold;"/>
```

bean:

```
private String myname;
private String message; 

public String sayHello()
{         
    message = "Hola " + myname;         
    return "";     
} 
public String getMyname() {
    return myname;
}

public void setMyname(String myname) {
    this.myname = myname;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

Everything works fine with ó and ễ and whatever.
jsf-1.2;trinidad1.2.14;apache tomcat6.0.29

I don't know the IBM WebSphere AS 7.0. But probably your problem has got something to do with what this guy is writing here: [Displaying UTF-8 Characters in resource response](http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2010/04/displaying-utf-8-characters-in-resource.html)